# Copy a specific row to new google sheet based on value in a cell in the row (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Google Script that copies rows from one Google Sheet into a different one based on the value of a cell.

I'd like the script to run and check the column "H" for word "done" and if it found then copy that row of data into the next empty row in the other sheet .

I tried different approaches, but still missing something. It always goes to "else" , so my guess is that the issue is with `var data = range.getValues();`

```
function transfer1() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet1test = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1test");
    var dbtest = ss.getSheetByName("dbtest2");


    var dataRange = sheet1test.getDataRange();
    var range = sheet1test.getRange("A2:H" + dataRange.getLastRow());
    var data = range.getValues();

    if ( data == "done" ) { //it seems that "done" is never found in any cell??

        dbtest.getRange(dbtest.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

    } else {

        do nothing

    }
}
```

I expect to only copy the rows that have value "done". What am I missing?

Comment: `getValues` returns "a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column" [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). So, "data" is an array and will never "equal" 'done'. Then there is the question of _which_ row to evaluate. Research some examples of looping through values returned by `getValues`. Also, take a look at the alternative `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) which includes a nice example of looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function yourfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,2,sh1.getLastRow(),7);//starting at column2
  var data=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][6]=="done") {
      sh2.appendRow(data[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

or this works to:

```
function yourfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,2,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn()-1);//starting at column2
  var data=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][6]=="done") {
      sh1.getRange(i+1,2,1,sh1.getLastColumn()-1).copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,sh1.getLastColumn()-1));
    }
  }
}
```

or even this:

```
function yourfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,2,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn()-1);//starting at column2
  var data=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][6]!="done") {
      data.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

actually this ones rather interesting:

```
function yourfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var data=rg1.getValues();
  data.map(function(r){return r.splice(0,1);});
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][6]!="done") {
      data.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```